# Blackberry OS5+ webworks application is terribly slow

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-os-v5

Iam developing a blackberry webworks application which is supposed to work on OS 5.0 and upwards.The app does use a fair bit of jquerymobile. The HTML's had already been developed and it was working well in the ripple emulator. But when I deployed it in an OS5.0 device, the load times were terrible. It took nearly a minute to load a page with some 3 images and a couple of tables (nothing was fetched from the server , all files were in the packaged application in the device). I even tried the pages on the native browser directly and its rendering capabilities were poor (css / jquery mobile etc came out horribly. Javascript was enabled in the device).

What I would like to know is, is native application/very basic html only way to get a decent experience on OS5.0? Is using fair bit of a javascript even feasible on OS5.0 HTML apps?
I even tried using a browserfield2 with caching but that too didnt make much difference.

Just wanted to see if things are indeed this bad in OS5.0 or if I missed something out. Any help/feedback will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: This is a known issue. Just google it, seems to be very common. For instance: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/application-slow-on-device-fast-on-simulator/td-p/833393